# How can i solve this error when importing materials?

Tags: materials, node-editor, add-on

When I try to add materials to Blender I have this error pop up, I tried importing different materials but without any luck.

````
bpy.context.space_data.recent_folders_active = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\addons\node_wrangler.py", line 2689, in execute
    if not active_node.bl_idname == 'ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bl_idname'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an active node selected and the Node Wrangler add-on had a bug that didn't check if an active node existed. Select the *Principled BSDF* node and it should work properly.

The bug in Node Wrangler has been [fixed](https://developer.blender.org/rBAb81b12e13fe930828021fc1690d5b7aa8c0e8b3c).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You should have a window with EEVEE viewport shading on and it will work

Answer (score 0):

It might be the *Relative Path* option pre-selected on the file viewer.

I unchecked it and then it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for some reason (even though you and I have probably had no problems before) blender cant load the textures from whatever drive they're currently on. Move the textures to the drive it says on the error and you should be fine despite the minor inconvenience. hope this helps someone as i'm sure you've figured it out already. GL